# Number of handles from Win8.1 task manager?

Tags: windows-8.1, task-manager

In win xp and win 7 we used to be able to see the number of handles and process etc, the actual count, in task manager like image here:
[image]

in win8.1 we have the resources manager:

[image]

but it doesnt give you a total count in one area for handles or processes threads. Any way to do this?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [new taskmanager](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/10/13/the-windows-8-task-manager.aspx) still shows the handles under Performance->CPU:

[image]

Comment: oh my goshhh you had to click it, sweeetnesss!!